# Swift Automatically change text field after pasting

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uicontrol

I have 3 textFields set up and I can manually type in the verification code and the cursor will move to the next textField after 4 characters.

But I also want this to happen when I paste the code into the first textField.. Currently it will just completely fill the first field and not populate the other boxes

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Get the users verification code form Firebase
    getCode()
    token1?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TokenViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    token2?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TokenViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    token3?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TokenViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)

}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == token1 {
        if (textField.text?.count)! >= 4 {
            token2?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    else if textField == token2 {
        if (textField.text?.count)! >= 4 {
            token3.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    else if textField == token3{
        if (textField.text?.count)! >= 4 {
            token3.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: as I see you are trying to implement PinCodeTextField, may be you should try this framework?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

        // ...


  if token1.text > 4 || token2.text > 4 || token3.text > 4 {

     let textFields = [token1, token2, token3]

      for token in textFields {

        if token.isFirstResponder {

     token1.text = token.text.prefix(4)
     token2.text = token.text.dropFirst(4).dropLast(4)
     token3.text = token.text.dropFirst(8)
                 }

            }
      }

}
```